# WIX - Unable to patch an installation after it has been patched

Tags: deployment, wix, wix3.5, setup-deployment

need a little help here...

**The Error** : *The upgrade patch cannot be installed by the Windows Installer service because the program to be upgraded may be missing, or the upgrade patch may update a different version of the program. Verify that the program to be upgraded exists on your computer and that you have the correct upgrade patch.*

I have done the following...

1. Created an MSI version 1.0 (GUID automatically created), ProductId="*"
2. Created a Patch (MSP) against the against the 1.0.wixpdb, version 1.1 (Update Code has been set), ProductId="{GUID1}", pyro gave a warning about changing the product code.
3. Created another Patch (MSP) against the 1.1.wixpdb, version 1.2 (Kept the same Update code). ProductId="{GUID1}", cannot install.

Scenario...
Install MSI v1.0 -> Install MSP 1.1 = Works fine.

Install MSI v1.0 -> Install MSP 1.1 -> Install MSP 1.2 = FAIL, windows cannot find the application.

Install MSI v1.1 -> Install MSP 1.2 = Works fine.

To me this means that when the first patch (1.1) went down something was potentially not update, or that in creating patch 1.2 i need to take 1.0 and 1.1 into account. I have tried various options, ranging from using  to  within the ...

Any ideas?

Update/Patch Code...

Product.wxs

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
    <Product Id="*"
        Name="WiX Patch Example Product"
        Language="1033"
        Version="1.0.0"
        Manufacturer="Dynamo Corporation"
        UpgradeCode="48C49ACE-90CF-4161-9C6E-9162115A54DD">

        <Package Description="Installs a file that will be patched."
            Comments="This Product does not install any executables"
            InstallerVersion="200"
            Compressed="yes" />

        <Media Id="1" Cabinet="product.cab" EmbedCab="yes" />
        <FeatureRef Id="SampleProductFeature"/>

    </Product>

    <Fragment>
        <Feature Id="SampleProductFeature" Title="Sample Product Feature" Level="1">
            <ComponentRef Id="File_1.txt" />
            <ComponentRef Id="File_2.txt" />
            <ComponentRef Id="File_3.txt" />

        </Feature>
    </Fragment>

    <Fragment>
        <DirectoryRef Id="SampleProductFolder">
            <Component Id="File_1.txt" Guid="{d738b2a9-0dbc-4381-9efd-5801723b1569}" DiskId="1">
                <File Id="File_1.txt" Name="File 1.txt" Source=".\$(var.Version)\File 1.txt" />             
            </Component>
            <Component Id="File_2.txt" Guid="{b9b267a3-5648-4e32-9ab1-f3032980f6c2}" DiskId="1">
                <File Id="File_2.txt" Name="File 2.txt" Source=".\$(var.Version)\File 2.txt" />             
            </Component>
            <Component Id="File_3.txt" Guid="{1df728ae-333d-47c5-9558-c0923f958a8d}" DiskId="1">                
                <File Id="File_3.txt" Name="File 3.txt" Source=".\$(var.Version)\File 3.txt" />
            </Component>            

        </DirectoryRef>
    </Fragment>

    <Fragment>
        <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
            <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder" Name="PFiles">
                <Directory Id="SampleProductFolder" Name="Patch Sample Directory">
                </Directory>
            </Directory>
        </Directory>
    </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

Product 1.1.wxs

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
    <Product Id="48C49ACE-90CF-4161-9C6E-9162115A54DD"
        Name="WiX Patch Example Product"
        Language="1033"
        Version="1.1.0"
        Manufacturer="Dynamo Corporation"
        UpgradeCode="48C49ACE-90CF-4161-9C6E-9162115A54DD">

        <Package Description="Installs a file that will be patched."
            Comments="This Product does not install any executables"
            InstallerVersion="200"
            Compressed="yes" />

        <Media Id="1" Cabinet="product.cab" EmbedCab="yes" />
        <FeatureRef Id="SampleProductFeature"/>

    </Product>

    <Fragment>
        <Feature Id="SampleProductFeature" Title="Sample Product Feature" Level="1">
            <ComponentRef Id="File_1.txt" />
            <ComponentRef Id="File_2.txt" />
            <ComponentRef Id="File_3.txt" />

            <ComponentRef Id="File_4.txt" />
        </Feature>
    </Fragment>

    <Fragment>
        <DirectoryRef Id="SampleProductFolder">
            <Component Id="File_1.txt" Guid="{d738b2a9-0dbc-4381-9efd-5801723b1569}" DiskId="1">
                <File Id="File_1.txt" Name="File 1.txt" Source=".\$(var.Version)\File 1.txt" />             
            </Component>
            <Component Id="File_2.txt" Guid="{b9b267a3-5648-4e32-9ab1-f3032980f6c2}" DiskId="1">
                <File Id="File_2.txt" Name="File 2.txt" Source=".\$(var.Version)\File 2.txt" />             
            </Component>
            <Component Id="File_3.txt" Guid="{1df728ae-333d-47c5-9558-c0923f958a8d}" DiskId="1">                
                <File Id="File_3.txt" Name="File 3.txt" Source=".\$(var.Version)\File 3.txt" />
            </Component>


            <Component Id="File_4.txt" Guid="{f728f62d-91f4-4c78-b2fe-65a9f0f6043c}" DiskId="1">                
                <File Id="File_4.txt" Name="File 4.txt" Source=".\$(var.Version)\File 4.txt" />
            </Component>        
        </DirectoryRef>
    </Fragment>

    <Fragment>
        <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
            <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder" Name="PFiles">
                <Directory Id="SampleProductFolder" Name="Patch Sample Directory">
                </Directory>
            </Directory>
        </Directory>
    </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

Product 1.2.wxs

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">

    <Product Id="48C49ACE-90CF-4161-9C6E-9162115A54DD"  
        Name="WiX Patch Example Product"
        Language="1033"
        Version="1.2.0"
        Manufacturer="Dynamo Corporation"
        UpgradeCode="48C49ACE-90CF-4161-9C6E-9162115A54DD">

        <Package Description="Installs a file that will be patched."
            Comments="This Product does not install any executables"
            InstallerVersion="200"
            Compressed="yes" />

        <Media Id="1" Cabinet="product.cab" EmbedCab="yes" />
        <FeatureRef Id="SampleProductFeature"/>

    </Product>

    <Fragment>
        <Feature Id="SampleProductFeature" Title="Sample Product Feature" Level="1">
            <ComponentRef Id="File_1.txt" />
            <ComponentRef Id="File_2.txt" />
            <ComponentRef Id="File_3.txt" />

            <ComponentRef Id="File_4.txt" />
        </Feature>
    </Fragment>

    <Fragment>
        <DirectoryRef Id="SampleProductFolder">
            <Component Id="File_1.txt" Guid="{d738b2a9-0dbc-4381-9efd-5801723b1569}" DiskId="1">
                <File Id="File_1.txt" Name="File 1.txt" Source=".\$(var.Version)\File 1.txt" />             
            </Component>
            <Component Id="File_2.txt" Guid="{b9b267a3-5648-4e32-9ab1-f3032980f6c2}" DiskId="1">
                <File Id="File_2.txt" Name="File 2.txt" Source=".\$(var.Version)\File 2.txt" />             
            </Component>
            <Component Id="File_3.txt" Guid="{1df728ae-333d-47c5-9558-c0923f958a8d}" DiskId="1">                
                <File Id="File_3.txt" Name="File 3.txt" Source=".\$(var.Version)\File 3.txt" />
            </Component>


            <Component Id="File_4.txt" Guid="{f728f62d-91f4-4c78-b2fe-65a9f0f6043c}" DiskId="1">                
                <File Id="File_4.txt" Name="File 4.txt" Source=".\$(var.Version)\File 4.txt" />
            </Component>        
        </DirectoryRef>
    </Fragment>

    <Fragment>
        <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
            <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder" Name="PFiles">
                <Directory Id="SampleProductFolder" Name="Patch Sample Directory">
                </Directory>
            </Directory>
        </Directory>
    </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

Patch 1.1

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
    <Patch 
        AllowRemoval="yes"
        Manufacturer="Dynamo Corp" 
        MoreInfoURL="http://www.dynamocorp.com/"
        DisplayName="Sample Patch" 
        Description="Small Update Patch" 
        Classification="Update"
        OptimizedInstallMode="yes">

        <Media Id="8000" Cabinet="RTM.cab" CompressionLevel="none">
            <PatchBaseline Id="RTM">

            </PatchBaseline>
        </Media>

        <PatchFamilyRef Id="SamplePatchFamily"/>    
    </Patch>

    <Fragment>    
        <PatchFamily Id='SamplePatchFamily' Version='1.1.0' Supersede='no'>


        </PatchFamily>
    </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

Patch 1.2

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
    <Patch 
        AllowRemoval="yes"
        Manufacturer="Dynamo Corp" 
        MoreInfoURL="http://www.dynamocorp.com/"
        DisplayName="Sample Patch" 
        Description="Small Update Patch" 
        Classification="Update"
        OptimizedInstallMode="yes">

        <Media Id="8000" Cabinet="RTM.cab" CompressionLevel="none">
            <PatchBaseline Id="RTM">

            </PatchBaseline>
        </Media>

        <PatchFamilyRef Id="SamplePatchFamily"/>    
    </Patch>

    <Fragment>    
        <PatchFamily Id='SamplePatchFamily' Version='1.2.0' Supersede='no'>


        </PatchFamily>
    </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

Comment: The issue seems to be, when the MSI was built, a autogenerated GUID was used. When patch 1.1 a different GUID was used... Any way to correct this or atleast perform an update for 1.2?

Comment: I have tried creating a wixmst from 1.0 to 1.2 and from 1.1 to 1.2, still does not work...

Answer (score 2):

Making your ProductId static will help with the patching scenario, every next patch will work.

But bare in mind that running a .msi e.g. version 1.5 after your version 1.3 patch (or even version 1.0 msi) will fail with: "Another version of the product is installed..." message. So while you're sticking with the same product id only provide the patches (.msp created from .msi), and when you wish to provide a new .msi make sure you change the product id.

I'm certainly too late with this answer, but I just wasted a whole work day on this issue, and decided to put it up so others won't have to.

I guess the two rules of MSI+MSP updates are:

1. Never make patches from MSIs with different product IDs, they will fail to find the product and will not run
2. Never provide different MSIs with same product IDs, they will fail with "another version installed" and will not run

It would have been much simpler if a different MSI just overwrote the previous one with the same product ID, but there must be a good reason for the way it is...

Answer (score 1):

You need a static product id across the board. You can use Orca to go in and find the product id from your 1.0 msi. Use that guid in your 1.1 and 1.2 product.wxs ProductId.